# Delayed Job is failing with no log or alert

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, delayed-job

Setting up a Delayed Job for the first time, and it is not working in my testing environment after following this [RailsCast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/171-delayed-job?view=asciicast).

I have two methods that I want to run - and in testing, I want to run them 15 seconds after a page loads. These methods are `calculate_rankings` and `update_wallet` from the **Participation.rb** model.

After installing the gem per the guide above, I am trying two things to debug: 1) I am running `rake jobs:work`, where there is no output after `Starting job worker`, and 2) I have added an alert to my controller's method, which does not activate.

Post-gem installation and **running the migration** (which was successful), I have made two changes in the code.

1. <del>Created **app/jobs/chipsupdater.rb**</del>

*This was the error. The file was incorrectly named and was therefore not called correctly in the controller. It should have been **app/jobs/chips_update_job.rb** based on the method I wrote below*.

```
     class ChipsUpdaterJob < Struct.new(:game_id)
        def perform
          Participation.calculate_ranking(game_id)
          Participation.update_wallet(game_id)
        end
       end
```

2. Updated my **ScoreboardController** that I want to initialize the delayed job:

   ```
   class ScoreboardController < ApplicationController
      def index

       @participations = Participation.where(finished: true, game_id: session[:game_id]).order(score: :desc).limit(10)
       @game = Game.find(params[:game_id])
      end
    def chipsupdater
       Delayed::Job.enqueue(ChipsUpdaterJob.new(params[:game_id]), :run_at => 1.minute.from_now) 
       flash[:notice] = "Things are good. Not broken."
      end 
    end
   ```

With no flash alert or output in the jobs console, my belief is that I am not correctly calling the Delayed Job. Can you spot where I am going wrong (or why I can't debug using the jobs console)?

**EDIT**

Per the discussion in the comments, I am now running the worker in a test environment. However, I am continuing to fail to a) post jobs to my `DelayedJobs` table or b) achieve our key output, which is to use the two methods in the ChipsUpdater Job file.

Thus, my belief is that I am failing to correctly call the delayed job based on this failure.

For context, I want to include two more potentially relevant files.

First, here is the Participation model that is referenced in the `ChipUpdaterJob`:

```
class Participation < ActiveRecord::Base

ef self.calculate_ranking(game_id)
      records = Participation.where(game_id: game_id, finished: true).order('score DESC, updated_at ASC')

      records.each_with_index do |record, index|
        puts "rank: #{index + 1}"
        puts record.inspect
        puts record['score']
        puts record['user_id']
        puts record['game_id']

        Ranking.create(game_id: game_id, user_id: record['user_id'], game_time: record['updated_at'], ranking: index + 1)
    end
  end
```

If this is taken out of a delay context and run as a normal method from the Scoreboard Controller, I have confirmed locally that it runs the ranking process successfully. The delay seems to be the failure.

**/bin/delayed_job**

```
require File.expand_path(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '..', 'config', 'environment'))

require 'delayed/command'
Delayed::Command.new(ARGV).daemonize
```

Comment: For anyone checking this, the delayed_job was not posting correctly because I had an incorrectly named file in my jobs folder. The underscores are key to correctly call the class in my controller.

Answer (score 2):

If youre trying to run a job in your testing environment then you need to set that environment when running the rake command

`RAILS_ENV=test bundle exec rake jobs:work`

also, try just printing instead of using a flash notice. a print will more likley show up on the tab you run the job from

can you confirm youre actually going to that `chipsupdater` route in one of your tests?

Comment: Thank you. I am least seeing errors now. When I try to load the worker in my test environment, I am getting an error for: `ctiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLite3::SQLException: no such table: delayed_jobs: SELECT  "delayed_jobs".* FROM "delayed_jobs"  WHERE ((run_at <= '2016-04-15 18:22:39.093284' AND (locked_at IS NULL OR locked_at` even though I have loaded the `delayedjobs` table with the migration from their GitHub.

Comment: you also need to run the post-install delayed job migration in the test environment. that error is telling you that your test database doesnt have a delayed jobs table (which is what the post install migration creates)

Comment: Ok, thanks to your advice, everything is now loading in the test environment. However, when reaching my Scoreboard controller, the background job is still not activating at the specified time, and the worker remains idle. I am thinking you are correct -- I do not have any routing for that `chipsupdater` class method. Do I need to call that in my Jobs file?

Comment: if you want it to run when you hit the index route, you need to call them method from the your index route, likely replacing `params[:game_id]` with an argument you pass to the method. can you describe when that method should get called

Comment: Great feedback here. In my test, I would like to have the enqueue method run the ChipsUpdater job (which contains two methods, outlined above) 1 minute from now, just to prove it works. The argument that needs to be passed is `game_id` which could be pulled as `@game.id` from the index action instead of checking the params. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add this line to config/application.rb

```
config.active_job.queue_adapter = :delayed_job
```